# OCaml - Map - how to "check" key and value?

Tags: dictionary, ocaml

How to create a Map that I will have a key: (int * int) and when it comes to key it is my_own_type ?

Comment: Please give more details. Can't understand your question.

Comment: OK, I would like to insert and find elements: (int * int) * (my_own_type). A assume that (int*int) will be key, and my_own_type will be value for key

Answer (score 2):

Here's a small example:

```
module IPMap = Map.Make(struct type t = int * int let compare = compare end)

let mymap = IPMap.add (0, 0) (my_value : my_own_type) IPMap.empty

let mymap' = IPMap.add (1, 2) (t: my_own_type) mymap
```

Note: you don't have to write `(t: my_own_type)`. You can just write `t`. I'm including it just for emphasis.

When you create a map module like IPMap, you only need to specify the type of the keys. You can have as many different maps with different value types as you like.

Note 2: OCaml maps are immutable. I worry that you haven't fully grappled with this issue yet. (Apologies if I'm wrong.)

Comment: Can you give me an axample ?
For instacnce. How to add (1,2) with value t ?

Comment: If a well understend it ?IPMap.add (1, 2) (t: my_own_type) mymap  It add to mymap key (1,2). For this key value is (t: my_own_type),

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't modify `mymap`. It creates a new map with all the keys and values from `mymap` plus the new key and value in it. OCaml maps are immutable (sorry to repeat).

Comment: Thanks you very much! So Map is functionla structure ? And I'm made to use let ?

Comment: Yes to both, though I'd say you have the pleasure of using `let` rather than being forced into it :-)